# Uncaught Type Error even when waiting for the webpage to load

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error when loading JavaScript onto my webpage

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'contentEditable' of null

However, I am waiting for the webpage to load before executing this so I can see no reason for the error.

JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = (function () {
  var doc = document.getElementById('doc');
  doc.contentEditable = true;
  doc.focus();
})();
```

HTML Snippet:

```html
<body>
    <header class="header">
      <h1 class="header__h1">editor</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="doc">
      <div class="doc__background-ribbon"></div>
      <div class="doc__text-editor hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="myfilehereexample"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are getting the element by id, but you have it as a class in your html.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an element with an `id` of `doc`. It has a `class` so `.getElementById` isn't going to work. Either change it to have an `id` or change the query to search for the class (shown below):

```js
window.onload = (function () {
  var doc = document.querySelector('.doc'); // Query for the first element with a class of "doc"
  doc.contentEditable = true;
  doc.focus();
})();
```

```html
    <header class="header">
      <h1 class="header__h1">editor</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="doc">Type here
      <div class="doc__background-ribbon"></div>
      <div class="doc__text-editor hidden"></div>
    </div>
```